# How can disposable class detect whether there is an exception in progress?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, idisposable, using-statement

I have a class that implements IDisposable

```
public class Foo: IDisposable {
    public void Dispose() {
        // do the disposing
    }
}
```

Then I have a method that uses the class in the following manner:

```
void Bar() {
    using (var f = new Foo()) {
       // do whatever
    }  
}
```

When the code leaves the using {...} boundary, the Dispose method on the Foo class gets called.  How can I detect in the Dispose method whether the code is leaving using block voluntarily or as a result of an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, to the best of my knowledge. Consider changing `Foo` to a method that takes the "body" to wrap and execute as a lambda:

```
Foo(f => {
    // do whatever
});
```

Then, your implementation of `Foo` can wrap the call into `try/catch` to detect exceptions and do whatever you want to do (and then rethrow using `throw;`).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that -- and I can't imagine a way to do that.

The main idea of implementing `IDisposable` is to ensure that resources are freed when destroying the object.

Now, the main idea of the `using` construct is to ensure that after it, all the resources used by the object are freed.

So, you should not depend on *why* the object is being disposed to perform this operation. If you do so, you should review your design.

Comment: There's a school of thought that views `IDisposable` and `using` as general-purpose RAII mechanisms, usable for more than freeing resources. In that scenario, it is perfectly normal to distinguish between "on success" and "on failure" scenarios - e.g. in D there's first-class language support for that, with `scope(success)` and `scope(failure)`; in C++, one would use `std::uncaught_exception()`; etc.

Comment: @Bruno.  Yes, what Pavel said.  The using keyword is absolutely awesome for scoping and using it in combination with Dispose is very powerful.

Comment: If the Dispose routine cannot revert things to an acceptable state, it should throw an exception.  At that point, both the disposal exception and the original exception should be propagated up (most cleanly by putting the original exception as an InnerException of the disposal exception).  For this to work, though, there has to be a way for the disposer to get the pending exception.